# How do I display the number of times the loop was entered?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, ipython

1. Ask the user to input an integer between 2 and 10 assign the integer to a variable x.
2. while x is less than 500, do the following inside a loop:

   2.1. print the current value of x

   2.2. update x so that it is double its previous value
3. After exiting the loop print the final value of x and the number of times the loop was entered.

This is what I have done I just don't understand how to get python to count the number of loops.

```
x = int(input("Enter an integer between 2 and 10: "))

while x < 500:

    print (x)

    x = x+x

print('The final value of x is', x)

print("The loop was entered, )
```

Example outputs:

```
Enter an integer between 2 and 10: 10
10
20
40
80
160
320
The final value of x is 640
The loop was entered 6 times.

Enter an integer between 2 and 10: 3
3
6
12
24
48
96
192
384
The final value of x is 768
The loop was entered 8 times.
```

If someone can explain the last string of code, I would appreciate it!

Comment: you need a separate counter variable that increments by one every time you loop

Comment: **Don't post links to images of code. Post the code _in the question_ as _formatted text_**

Comment: that was not an image of code, it was an image of the output so you can get idea as to what i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be like that:

```
cnt = 0
x = int(input("Enter an integer between 2 and 10: "))
while x < 500:
    print (x)
    x = x+x
    cnt = cnt+1

print('The final value of x is', x)

print('The loop was entered', cnt)
```